# How to check if file is being used by another process - Powershell

Tags: .net, file, powershell

I am trying to find a solution which will check whether a file is being used by another process. I don't want to read the contents of the file, as on a 7GB document, this could take a while. Currently I am using the function mentioned below, which is not ideal as the script takes about 5 - 10  minutes to retrieve a value.

```
function checkFileStatus($filePath)
{
    write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILECHECK] Checking if" $filePath "is locked"

    if(Get-Content $filePath  | select -First 1)
    {
        write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILEAVAILABLE]" $filePath
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILELOCKED] $filePath is locked"
        return $false
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Created a function which solves the above problem:

```
 function checkFileStatus($filePath)
    {
        write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILECHECK] Checking if" $filePath "is locked"
        $fileInfo = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $filePath

        try 
        {
            $fileStream = $fileInfo.Open( [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::Read )
            write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILEAVAILABLE]" $filePath
            return $true
        }
        catch
        {
            write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILELOCKED] $filePath is locked"
            return $false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. It is very useful. I am using it to test if a file on a shared network location is available for use. Every a few days they upload a new big file to that location (which takes a few hours to upload) and I want to make sure that the uploading is finished so that I can safely copy and download that file to my local machine. Do you see any flaw in my concept?

Comment: Is there a reason that this doesn't call `$fileStream.Dispose()` before exiting?

Comment: @user2426679 I've read that garbage collector will take care of it, unless you are creating too many objects within a certain timeframe

Comment: This actually doesn't work as written for me, needed to replace `$fileStream = $fileInfo.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::Read)` with `$fileStream = $fileInfo.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write, [System.IO.FileShare]::Read)` to trigger an error when the file was being used by another process.

Comment: all the solutions here are returning false positive for me. like the file is always locked

Answer (score 9):

The function i use to check whether a file is locked or not :

```
function IsFileLocked([string]$filePath){
    Rename-Item $filePath $filePath -ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    return ($errs.Count -ne 0)
}
```

Comment: For my case this didn't work. I want to copy over an existing file, so I ran this check on it and got no errors, but when it got to the copy step, there was an error that the file was being used by another process.

Answer (score 5):

```
function IsFileAccessible( [String] $FullFileName )
{
  [Boolean] $IsAccessible = $false

  try
  {
    Rename-Item $FullFileName $FullFileName -ErrorVariable LockError -ErrorAction Stop
    $IsAccessible = $true
  }
  catch
  {
    $IsAccessible = $false
  }
  return $IsAccessible
}
```

Comment: Add some comments to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this script on [poschcode.org](http://poshcode.org/1363):

```
filter Test-FileLock {
    if ($args[0]) {$filepath = gi $(Resolve-Path $args[0]) -Force} else {$filepath = gi $_.fullname -Force}
    if ($filepath.psiscontainer) {return}
    $locked = $false
    trap {
        Set-Variable -name locked -value $true -scope 1
        continue
    }
    $inputStream = New-Object system.IO.StreamReader $filepath
    if ($inputStream) {$inputStream.Close()}
    @{$filepath = $locked}
}
```

Comment: FYI that's not a PoshCode link.

Comment: Thanks, with the helping of the link, I created a new function which does what is required.

Comment: @user983965, if you were able to solve your problem you should post the solution as an answer on SO. Links to solutions are less useful because the target page can change or disappear.

Comment: @DourHighArch or be a bad website

Answer (score 1):

SInce you don't want to read the file, I would recommend using a utility like Sysinternals Handle.exe, which will spit out all open handles for a process. You can download Handle.exe from here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655

You can run Handle.exe without any arguments, and it will return all open file handles. You can parse the output if necessary, or just match the output against your full file path.

Answer (score 1):

I want to correct above answer:

```
 function checkFileStatus($filePath)
    {
        write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILECHECK] Checking if" $filePath "is locked"
        $fileInfo = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $filePath

        try 
        {
            $fileStream = $fileInfo.Open( [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::None )
            write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILEAVAILABLE]" $filePath
            $fileStream.Dispose()
            return $true
        }
        catch
        {
            write-host (getDateTime) "[ACTION][FILELOCKED] $filePath is locked"
            return $false
        }
    }
```

If you try to open file with [FileShare]::Read, it could be opened if other process also specified this (or less restricitve) FileShare mode. So, you must use [FileShare]::None, as most restrictive and incompatible with any other mode - so if file opened by another process in any way, it will be failed to open by script.

Also filestream should be disposed, otherwise file may remain opened for indefinite amount of time.