# Identify that file is not being use by any other process

Tags: file, powershell-2.0

In my sceniro I am checking the file in a particluar folder and checking whether it exists or not. In case it exists i am doing some operations on it.
But my issue is that these files are getting generated by other process [which usally takes 20-30 min to generate the file], so for example at any instance when I checked the file in the folder and I find it. Now, I need to make sure that it is not in process right now so that I can continue my operation on that it. Below is the code snippet which I am using:

*EDIT*
My question is this that how can I identify that file is not in use (or is getting generated) by other process.

```
    $Filesitems = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\SomeFolder\Sub_Folder"


foreach ($objItem in $Filesitems)
{

      if ($objItem.Name.Contains("Process"))
      {
            Write-Host $objItem.Name
      }
}
```

Comment: @joachim My question is this that how can I identify that file is not in use (or is getting generated) by other process.

Comment: Would it be possible to generate the file in a temp directory and just move it to the correct place once it's done?

Comment: I don't have control on that process. Files are getting generated on that folder only.

Comment: Is the problem that the file is locked and you're getting an error when attempting to open it or that it's not locked and you're reading an incomplete file?

Comment: Yeah, actually when file is available I have to run SSIS packages but they hang & showed error because packages won't able to read the file. There packages got stuck at the code which is getting the list of files present in the respective folder.

Comment: You may want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11213394/477878).

Comment: +1 that seems to be what I am looking.. I will check all of them and update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try to use a 'lock'-file to avoid this behavior.

Ensure whenever the process works on the file, the process also generates an (empty) file.lock file and removes it when the process is finished working on the file.

In this scenario you can check whether a lockfile exists, and so you know that another process is still working on that particular file

Comment: That is nice suggestion but I have no control over that process . :(

Comment: Is there something at the end of the file that is always getting written last. Like EOF or some such?
... otherwise you will have to drop down to filesystem level and see if you can find out in what state the file is. i do not know how to do this, i'm afraid :)

Comment: File generate with some column and row delimiter but that won't help us. But do you mean that Filestram properties like IsReadOnly can work in these scenarios ?

Comment: they might. but I don't have any knowledge in that regard. sorry! it depends on how the process is opening/writing/closing the file