# How to get Write Access to a file/directory locked by another process - Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've a powershell script which performs some operations on pdf files, email as attachments, then moves the files to an archive.
Script worked properly for about 2 years, however recently I (and also the clients) started getting this error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'file_name' because it is being used by another process.
```

From following question I've determined how to check if a file/folder is locked,
[How to check if file is being used by another process - Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394629/how-to-check-if-file-is-being-used-by-another-process-powershell)

**My Question:** 

How can I get write access to some file or directory locked by another process?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: You'd have to terminate the other process. However, that may result in data loss, so you probably don't want to do it. Try to identify the process locking the file(s) and determine why it's keeping them open.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar for your reply. The files themselves are downloaded from other machines using another script, so data loss is not an issue. Looks like script has read-only access to the content ( reported by PS as "being used by another process")

Comment: In that case you'll need to grant write access to the user running the script. There are various ways to do this, but personally I find [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) the most convenient (scriptable) solution: `icacls file_name /grant username:M`.