# Copy files which are complete?

Tags: powershell

While running a command to copy files from source to destination using powershell, I ran into the problem of how to only copy files which do not have any operation running on them?

If there are 3 files A/B/C, logging is still happening on A, while B and C are complete. I only want to copy B and C using powershell.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: This should let you identify files, if are being used by another process. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9411199/5212566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can start with:

```
function Test-FileNotInUse 
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)] [Alias('FullName')] [string] $filePath
    )

    process {

        $inUse = $false

        try {
            $fileInfo = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $filePath
            $fileStream = $fileInfo.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)

            if ($fileStream) {
                $fileStream.Close()
            }
        }

        catch {
            $inUse = $true
        }

        if (!$inUse) {
            Write-Output $filePath
        }
    }
}


$source = "C:\source"
$destination = "C:\destination"

dir $source -recurse | Test-FileNotInUse | %{ copy $_ $destination }
```